# Get user feed with Facebook access token from app

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

For a website i'm building a need to get Facebook feed from a users page and display it on a website. I've been able to get this working, only i'm using an user-access-token, which expires in about 2 hours.

Is there any solution on how i can display the users feed on my website and don't need to refresh the access token all the time? I also created an Facebook App, but when i try do use that app-access-token in my code i get an error. Saying i can not use that for user feed requests.

I use graph to get all the users feed in JSON.
Hopefully someone can explain to me how i can get a user-acces-token that won't expire or how i can use my app-access-token to get the feed from the user.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't get an access token that doesn't expire, but you can get an extended life access token which can last for 60 days.  Information about access tokens and various types of them can be found here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

More specifically about extending access tokens:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending

Comment: Thanks. I already knew you can get i 60-day-token, sorry for not mentioning that in my first post. But i think it is strange that there is no other way than refreshing your user access token every 60 days to get the feed...Is there really no other way than refresh the token all the time?

Comment: No, there is no other way.

Comment: So every website that wants to stream feed from a user (or users) to their website has to change the access token every 2 hours?

Comment: They have to get an extended access token or yes, that is what they need if that information is not public or can't be accessed by an app token.